# What will be the complexity of $T(n) =T(n/4) +T(n/2) +n^2?$

Tags: recurrence-relations, asymptotics

I need to solve this using the substitution method where you assume a solution and prove it using induction. Help.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I think you will get an idea by considering $n$ to be a power of $2$ first. If $n=2^k,$ can you find $f(n)$ in terms of $n$ or $k$?

Comment: I assumed n^2 to be the value.
For t(n) <= cn^2
When you substitute the value of 2n/3 and n/2,
I'm getting 
c1*n^2/16 + c2*n2/4 + n^2 <= c1*n^2
How do i proceed after this?

Answer (score 1):

The Ansatz $T(n)=cn^p$ gives $cn^p(1-1/4^p-1/2^p)=n^2$ so $p=2,\,c=\frac{1}{1-1/16-1/4}=\frac{16}{11}$. You're welcome to further investigate the asymptotic behaviour of$$U(n):=\frac{11T(n)}{16n^2}=\frac{11(T(n/4)+T(n/2)+n^2)}{16n^2}=\frac{U(n/4)}{16}+\frac{U(n/2)}{4}+\frac{11}{16},$$to motivate $U(n)\to1$ as $n\to\infty$. Certainly, if a finite $L:=\lim_{n\to\infty}U(n)$ exists then $L=\frac{5L+11}{16}\implies L=1$.

Comment: I am not familiar with this method.

Comment: I assumed n^2 to be the value.
For t(n) <= cn^2
When you substitute the value of 2n/3 and n/2,
I'm getting 
c1*n^2/16 + c2*n2/4 + n^2 <= c1*n^2
How do i proceed after this?

Comment: @Jake What's $2n/3$ got to do with it?